# Lua/C++ : __index is always invoked even the table's field is known

Tags: c++, lua

I would like to declare global metatables in Lua that are registered by a C++ app.

I define the __index metamethod of the metatable and some fields but when the lua script access known fields, the __index is always invoked in my C++ app.

For example I want to register a global table named *User* which contains three fields : *FirstName*, *LastName* and *Age*.

Here is how I register the table. The table is encapsulated in a class named TLuaStruct that make easier to register table in Lua.

```
bool TLuaStruct::InternalRegister( std::string tName, bool AddInGC )
{
    TLuaStack *ptStack;
    TLuaStruct **ptUserLuaStruct;

    ptStack = m_ptLua->GetStack();
    if( ptStack==NULL )
        return false;

    //  Create a metatable that won't be exposed to Lua scripts.
    //  The name must be unique
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  1,-1 | table
    m_ptLua->NewMetaTable( m_tMetaName );

    //  Register all of the properties
    PushProperties( false, false );

    //  Register the callback assigned to __index
    ptStack->PushCFunction( TLuaStruct_Index_CallBack );

    m_ptLua->SetField( -2, "__index" );

    // Create a UserData to store the address of this.
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  2,-1 | userdata
    //  1,-2 | table
    ptUserLuaStruct = ( TLuaStruct** )m_ptLua->NewUserData( sizeof( ptUserLuaStruct ) );
    *ptUserLuaStruct = this;
    m_pvLuaThisPtr = ( void* )ptUserLuaStruct;

    //  Switch the userdata and the table
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  2,-1 | table
    //  1,-2 | userdata
    ptStack->Insert( -2 );

    //  Associate the metatable to the userdata
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  1,-1 | userdata
    m_ptLua->SetMetaTable( -2 );

m_ptLua->SetGlobal( tName.c_str() );

    return true;
}
```

If I assign the metatable itself to __index instead to a C callback, the scripts can access *FirstName*, *LastName* and *Age* in readonly (What I would like to do) but I can't know when the scripts try to access an unknown field cause my C++ app is not invoked.

Maybe Lua always invokes __index when the metatable is userdata so it makes sure the values are up-to-date but it could be nice to defined read-only variable such as function in a table otherwise calling __index all the time can slow down the app.

Is anyone know how to perform this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't add the solution to the question, leave the question as it was. Instead, post an answer to your own question.

Comment: Yes, but riv's answer is almost right too.

Comment: @A.G. I agree with Yu Hao, you should post the answer. You don't have to mark it as the accepted answer, you can leave Riv's as accepted. Your answer will likely get upvoted, thus letting others new to this thread know that it should be considered too. With your answer inline with your question, there is no way to differentiate the value of your answer from that of the question.

Comment: Just a note, be careful using the words "static" vs "dynamic" members: static means non-stack or class-wide in C++ (which you are using) and many other OO languages. By the looks of it, you mean either read-only or const, ie their value can't change, or the member cannot be removed from the object/table (which in Lua means setting to nil).

Comment: @Scholli: You're right I'll change my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual does a good job of explaining how metatables work, perhaps you misread it - arbitrary fields in a metatable have no effect, only `__index` adds "fake" fields to the object.

The best solution would be to put all static values in the `__index` table, then create *another* metatable for the `__index` table, and set *its* `__index` field to your function.

**Update:**
As other have mentioned, a slightly more compact solution exists: set the first metatable's `__index` to itself (and fill it with static values), and set *its* metatable to another metatable, which has your function as its `__index`.

Comment: I already tried to create a metatable #1, put my static values in it, create another metatable #2 put my function in its __index then put metatable #2 in __index of metatable #1 and finally set the metatable of the userdata with metatable #1. But this does not work at all, it's worst. could you please provide a sample ? I tried to do this in a Lua script and it works fine but not in C, I guess I do something wrong, but I still don't have figured out what. [I used the tutorial there](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetamethodsTutorial)

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION:**

Riv was almost right with its solution but there's a small difference so I post a new answer.

The solution is to set the main metatable's __index to itself, create a second metatable in which its __index is set to a C callback function, and set this new metatable **as the metatable** of the main metatable and not its __index.

```
bool TLuaStruct::InternalRegister( std::string tName, bool AddInGC )
{
    TLuaStack *ptStack;
    TLuaStruct **ptUserLuaStruct;

    ptStack = m_ptLua->GetStack();
    if( ptStack==NULL )
        return false;

    //  Create a metatable that won't be exposed to Lua scripts.
    //  The name must be unique
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  1,-1 | table
    m_ptLua->NewMetaTable( m_tMetaName );

    //  Register all of the const members 
    PushProperties( false, false );

    //  Duplicate the metatable
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  2,-1 | table
    //  1,-2 | table
    ptStack->PushValue( -1 );

    //  Set its __index to itself so it can access all of its const members
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  1,-1 | table
    m_ptLua->SetField( -2, "__index" );


    //  Create another metable that will be used for non-const members
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  2,-1 | table
    //  1,-2 | table
    m_ptLua->NewMetaTable( "9999" );

    //  Push the C call back called when a non-const member is read
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  3,-1 | function
    //  2,-2 | table
    //  1,-3 | table
    ptStack->PushCFunction( TLuaStruct_Index_CallBack );

    //  Set the __index of the metable
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  2,-1 | table
    //  1,-2 | table
    m_ptLua->SetField( -2, "__index" );


    //  Set the metatable of the main metatable
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  1,-1 | table
    m_ptLua->SetMetaTable( -2 );

    // Create a UserData to store the address of this.
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  2,-1 | userdata
    //  1,-2 | table
#warning check whether we must create a new pointer each time...
    ptUserLuaStruct = ( TLuaStruct** )m_ptLua->NewUserData( sizeof( ptUserLuaStruct ) );
    *ptUserLuaStruct = this;
    m_pvLuaThisPtr = ( void* )ptUserLuaStruct;

    //  Switch the userdata and the table
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  2,-1 | table
    //  1,-2 | userdata
    ptStack->Insert( -2 );

    //  Set the metatable of the userdata
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  1,-1 | userdata
    m_ptLua->SetMetaTable( -2 );

    //  Publish the userdata object with the name of the module.
    //  Stack after the call:
    //  -- empty --
    m_ptLua->SetGlobal( tName.c_str() );

    return true;
}
```